# Can xor and xnor for quasi-reduced BDDs be implemented just like union?

Tags: algorithms, logic, binary-trees

Below is an algorithm for union of two quasi reduced BDDs `p` and `q` resulting in `r`.

```
bdd Union(bdd p, bdd q) 
  local bdd r;
1 if p=0 or q=1 then return q;
2 if q=0 or p=1 then return p;
3 if p=q then return p;
4 if Cachecontainsentry⟨UnionCODE,{p,q}:r⟩ then return r;
  //p.lvl = q.lvl in case of quasi reduced BDDs
5 r ← UniqueTableInsert(p.lvl, Union(p[0], q[0]), Union(p[1], q[1]));
6 enter⟨UnionCODE,{p,q}:r⟩ in Cache;
7 return r;
```

Since there is no variable skipping, `p.lvl` is always equal to `q.lvl`. I have a question about this algorithm.

If I want to implement Xor or Xnor for quasi-reduced BDDs, can it be done the same way as union or should I implement the expression `pq' + p'q` where `q' = !q`.

Comment: Can you write your algorithm in pseudocode? We don't know what the various functions you call do (for example, what order are their parameters).

Comment: What are "quasi-reduced" BDDs, is that a standard notion? Have you tried the algorithm for some examples?

Comment: How does this differ from [your older question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13637/difference-between-fully-reduced-bdd-and-quasi-reduced-bdd), besides being condiderably less meaty? (Moderator's note: please register an account so you can take proper ownership of your posts; you will be able to edit, then.)

Comment: It differs from my older question that was conversion of algorithm from fully-reduced to quasi reduced. I was asked by a moderator to create a separate post for this algorithm. I am a registered user to answer your second question.

Comment: Quasi-reduced BDDs are produced when we merge the nodes of OBDD such that every non-terminal node has children. In case of Fully-reduced, the redundant nodes of OBDD are merged as well as deleted.